# Calculus book with big/ little oh

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, book-recommendation

Is there an introductory calculus textbook out there that makes good use of big/ little oh notation?  Things like defining the derivative $f'(a)$ as the number such that $$f(a+\epsilon) = f(a) + f'(a)\epsilon + o(\epsilon)$$

or using big Oh for Taylor's theorem, etc.

Comment: Why do you think that would be good?

Comment: I don't know for sure that it would.  I was trying to explain little oh notation and how useful it is in proving theorems about the derivative to a friend of mine who's taking calculus at the moment and I was looking for a reference that she could look through with several examples at her level.

Comment: Fair enough. Happy hunting for a suitable book - I'm afraid I don't know of one.